# Drupal 7 - Some disabled modules did not show up in the uninstall list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

**I have created a local copy of my website, now, I can disable modules but not all of them are showing up in the uninstall list.**

For example, the following modules are already disabled but I did not see them in the uninstall list:

> Aggregator 7.27    Aggregates syndicated content (RSS, RDF, and Atom
>   feeds).
>
> AntiSpam 7.x-1.5+20-dev    Use the Akismet, Defensio or TypePad AntiSpam
>   services to protect your site from spam.
>
> Author Pane 7.x-2.0-beta1  Gathers information from core and user
>   related contrib modules and displays it in a template.
>
> Auto Assign Role 7.x-1.x-dev   Automatically assign a role to new
>   users.

Answer (score 0):

Not all modules can/need to be uninstalled.

From the documentation [Uninstalling modules](https://drupal.org/node/250783):

> Not all modules have specific uninstall functions programmed in. A module will only show up on the uninstall tab if it has this feature. If it doesn't, skip this step and simply delete its files.

Comment: Note that [Aggregator](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator) is a core module, so you should better not delete its files; just keep it disabled if you don’t need it.